# Delete unique term from array with regex

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose I have an array

```
@arr = qw( 12 2 5 bba<1s54> 10 11 )
```

How I can delete non-numeric items from this array, in this case `"bba<1s54>"`?

This unique "term" has format `"bba<...>"`.  Is it possible to use regex to delete it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `grep` the result for numbers only:

```
my @arr = qw(12 2 5 bba<1s54> 10 11);
@arr = grep /^\pN+$/, @arr;
```

If you know exactly what to remove, it is stricter to just remove that. E.g.:

```
@arr = grep !/bba<.*>/, @arr;
```

Comment: @TomErdos Of course it works. If you're happy with the answer, click the checkmark to accept it.